# Latex output in Julia with Symbolics.jl

Tags: julia, latex, atom-editor, symbolic-math

I am new in Julia and using Symbolics. I wanna make Latex output. In [Symbolics' docs](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/dev/tutorials/symbolic_functions/) there is an easy example:

```
using Latexify
latexify(A) # A - some symbolic expression
```

And in their example they have a beautiful Latex output. But in my case I have Latex code as output.

```
julia> expr = 2x + y^2
       2x + y^2

julia> latexify(expr)
 L"\begin{equation*}
 2 x + y^{2}
 \end{equation*}
"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

latexify produces an LaTeXString objects that does not provide any visualization of its own. However there are many renderers that can display contents having`text/latex` MIME type. Have a look at https://github.com/stevengj/LaTeXStrings.jl

Perhaps your best bet is IJulia (Jupyter notebook)

[image]

Note that `Symbolics` object get correctly displayed regardless whether you use `latexify`.

Another possible renderers could be plotting packages that support LaTeX annotations on plots via functions such as `annotate!`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `render(latexify(expr))`. It should work in Atom:
https://korsbo.github.io/Latexify.jl/stable/#External-rendering